# boost::range::combine with repeated argument

Tags: c++11, boost, variadic-templates, boost-range

I would like to use `boost::range::combine` as a cartesian power instead as just a product.

So instead of such expression `boost::range::combine(myRange, myRange, myRange);` write something like `myCombine(myRange, 3);`.

How it can be implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementing this in C++17 or C++14 would be a lot easier and cleaner, but since you tagged this with [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) here's a compliant implementation. Here's a generic way of calling a *function object* `f` with the same argument repeated `N` times.

First, we need a way of binding the first argument of a generic *function object* `f` and then accepting any number of arguments:

```
template <typename TF, typename T>
struct bound
{
    TF _f;
    T _x;

    template <typename TFFwd, typename TFwd>
    bound(TFFwd&& f, TFwd&& x)
        : _f{std::forward<TFFwd>(f)}, _x{std::forward<TFwd>(x)}
    {
    }

    template <typename... Ts>
    auto operator()(Ts&&... xs)
        -> decltype(_f(_x, std::forward<Ts>(xs)...))
    {
        return _f(_x, std::forward<Ts>(xs)...);
    }
};

template <typename TF, typename T>
auto bind_first(TF&& f, T&& x)
    -> decltype(bound<TF&&, T&&>(std::forward<TF>(f), std::forward<T>(x)))
{
    return bound<TF&&, T&&>(std::forward<TF>(f), std::forward<T>(x));
}
```

Then, we need a recursive `helper` that will bind an argument `x` multiple `TN` times:

```
template <std::size_t TN>
struct helper
{
    template <typename TF, typename T>
    auto operator()(TF&& f, T&& x)
        -> decltype(helper<TN - 1>{}(bind_first(std::forward<TF>(f), x), x))
    {
        return helper<TN - 1>{}(bind_first(std::forward<TF>(f), x), x);
    }
};

template <>
struct helper<0>
{
    template <typename TF, typename T>
    auto operator()(TF&& f, T&& x)
        -> decltype(f(x))
    {
        return f(x);
    }
};
```

Finally, we can provide a nice interface:

```
template <std::size_t TN, typename TF, typename T>
auto call_with_same_arg(TF&& f, T&& x)
    -> decltype(helper<TN - 1>{}(std::forward<TF>(f), std::forward<T>(x)))
{
    return helper<TN - 1>{}(std::forward<TF>(f), std::forward<T>(x));
}
```

Usage:

```
int add(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return a + b + c;   
}

int main()
{
    assert(call_with_same_arg<3>(add, 5) == 15);
}
```

[**live wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/0NLhiGu3sojnitMu)

---

Here's a complete C++17 implementation of the same thing:

```
template <std::size_t TN, typename TF, typename T>
decltype(auto) call_with_same_arg(TF&& f, T&& x)
{
    if constexpr(TN == 1)
    {
        return f(x);
    }
    else
    {
        return call_with_same_arg<TN - 1>(
            [&](auto&&... xs){ return f(x, std::forward<decltype(xs)>(xs)...); }, x);
    }
}
```

[**live wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/w5kTM1ewOtRRQNc2)

---

For completeness, C++14 implementation:

```
template <std::size_t TN>
struct helper
{
    template <typename TF, typename T>
    decltype(auto) operator()(TF&& f, T&& x)
    {
        return helper<TN - 1>{}(
            [&](auto&&... xs){ return f(x, std::forward<decltype(xs)>(xs)...); }, x);
    }
};

template <>
struct helper<0>
{
    template <typename TF, typename T>
    decltype(auto) operator()(TF&& f, T&& x)
    {
        return f(x);
    }
};

template <std::size_t TN, typename TF, typename T>
decltype(auto) call_with_same_arg(TF&& f, T&& x)
{
    return helper<TN - 1>{}(std::forward<TF>(f), std::forward<T>(x));
}
```

[**live wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/qYs82b1vTWyR3tUf)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If you have in mind solutions for other c++ standards feel free to write them here. I just wrote c++11, to show that it is probably (and it is) template meta programming tricks.

Comment: Ou, ok you've just posted c++17 version. Is there something for c++14 with same easy solution for c++17?

Comment: @YaroslavKishchenko: it's a little longer, but better than C++11. Will post it in a sec.

Comment: @YaroslavKishchenko: done. You basically don't need `bound` or `bind_first`.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I will analyze you answer and then approve it))

Comment: @YaroslavKishchenko Please don't forget to accept the answer.